# Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement

Tags: mysql, parameters, executemany

Thanks for reading my post.

I want to do a easy thing: take info from one database and inject into another.

`PRAGMA_fl_product = ACCESS_cursor.execute('SELECT Prekes.PrekeID, Prekes.NomNr, AmburiaSandLik.Likutis, Prekes.PardKaina, AmburiaSandLik.Likutis, Prekes.PardKaina FROM Prekes INNER JOIN AmburiaSandLik ON Prekes.PrekeID=AmburiaSandLik.PrekeID;').fetchall()`

```
flproduct="INSERT INTO fl_product (product_id, model, quantity, prices, status) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '1') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE quantity='%s', price='%s'"
SQLcursor.executemany(flproduct, PRAGMA_fl_product)
```

And this throws an error:

```
SQLcursor.executemany(flproduct, PRAGMA_fl_product)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 606, in executemany
stmt = self._batch_insert(operation, seq_params)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 553, in _batch_insert
"Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement")
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement
```

Can someone help me understand the problem that I am facing?

I SELECT 6 columns and try to use 6 '%s' escape entries, but seem to miss some thing.

Comment: Are the two databases on the same server, or are you copying between different servers?

Comment: OK. If they were the same server you could do it in one query, but not with separate servers.

Comment: what do you mean? these are to different executions: one is SELECT and one is INSERT

Comment: I mean you could write `INSERT into db1.table_1 SELECT columns FROM db2.table_2`

Comment: @Barmar I think he is using 2 different connections, to the 2 different databases, which is quite possible to do. If only the queries were correctly coded

Comment: @RiggsFolly I know. That was the point of my earlier question. When he said that they were different servers, I explained that this one-query solution won't work.

Comment: See your `flproduct="INSERT....` query. You have 4 columns mentioned `(product_id, model, quantity, prices)` but 5 data parameters being passed in i.e. `VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', 1)` which rather fits with the error message __Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement__

Comment: @Barmar But I dont see a `one-query` anywhere in the question

Comment: @RiggsFolly I know. I was saying that if he was using a single server, I would then show how to do it with a single query instead of the way he's doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this question because I had a similar situation:

```
curs.execute('INSERT INTO tbl (a, b) VALUES (%s, %s) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE b = %s', (1,2,2))
```

Which was giving the same error when called. When I changed the query to named parameters:

```
curs.execute('INSERT INTO tbl (a, b) VALUES (%(a)s, %(b)s) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE b = %(b)s', {a: 1, b: 2})
```

This errored with:

> mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%(b)s' at line 1

From this I concluded that the connector doesn't recognise parameters after UPDATE. So my workaround was:

```
curs.execute('INSERT INTO tbl (a, b) VALUES (%(a)s, %(b)s) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE b = VALUES(b)', {a: 1, b: 2})
```

Which uses the VALUES function to get the new value that would have been written, if there wasn't a duplicate key error. See [mysql docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_values).

In your case, this would be:

```
flproduct="INSERT INTO fl_product (product_id, model, quantity, prices, status) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '1') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE quantity=VALUES(quantity), prices=VALUES(prices)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your INSERT is wrong.

```
INSERT INTO fl_product
(product_id, model, quantity, prices)
VALUES
('%s'      , '%s' , '%s'    , '%s'  , 1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE quantity='%s', price='%s'"
```

There are 5 values and 4 columns selected. What's with the number `1` ?

Comment: Dear Phiter, thanks for your answer. I get the same error if I select 4 columns or 5. But thanks for noticing, maybe any more ideas? The "1" is for adding "1" to all the fields in the status column that are inserted.

 INSERT INTO fl_product
(product_id, model, quantity, prices, status)
VALUES
('%s'      , '%s' , '%s'    , '%s'  , 1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE quantity='%s', price='%s'"